# Using jquery ready() function but still not fast enough? Ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, document-ready

Small question that I hope someone can answer.

I'm creating this personal chrome extension to help me test out content manipulation on various sites.  On one of these sites, I am simply replacing an existing `<img>` with a different image and wrapping that jquery `replaceWith()` function in `$(document).ready()` function.

When navigating to the page, though, you can still see the original image for a split second before it swaps them.

Is there any way to arrest the loading page until the image swap completes?

Comment: This is a great question, but unfortunately without native access to the DOM construction (ie. html or stylesheet), you'll have to wait for element construction before you can manipulate it.

Comment: Using `.live()` or `.delegate()` _might_ execute as elements become available before document ready state, but it probably won't. It all depends on how/when/what browsers execute during rendering.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, the `<img>` element is uniquely identifiable in some way (such as it's `src` attribute or an `id`).  If that's the case, quickly add a stylesheet when the document is created, this stylesheet should target the `<img>` element and hide it from site.  Then, during your `.ready()` handler, disable/remove the stylesheet.

```
var ss = document.createElement("style");
ss.textContent = "img[src='/path/to/img.png'] { visibility: hidden; }";
document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(ss);

$(document).ready(function () { 
    ss.parentNode.removeChild(ss);

    // swap image here
});
```

Comment: Doesn't Chrome come with a stylesheet option for content scripts?

Answer (score 2):

no. any attempt to do that will result in the page not being "ready" which will result in you not reaching a state where you can swap the image out.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea - not sure whether this will work, but if you're desperate, it's worth a try.

Put in a `$('img').live('onload', function(){...})` where you replace the image `src` either with an url that points to a blank image, or nothing at all. That should be fast enough to stop the image from showing, and then when `document.ready` calls, you can replace the images in question.

Comment: There is still a chance that the image will load first, depending on when jQuery and the rest of his JavaScript gets loaded.

Comment: Well yes, obviously the javascript code for this will need to be loaded first for it to help - if that's not possible, there's not much hope.

Comment: Since it's a chrome extension, I am not sure I can directly control where the script gets loaded.

Comment: @Chaz: even so, with this method it would be done at the soonest possible time, given your constraints - which might be slightly sooner than $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

This could be difficult to handle because after the page load event is completed you need to wait until image is loaded completely and you cannot avoid this. but you can use something like this:

you can set an image loading source before the final image is loaded successfully

`$('imageControl').load(function(){ 

    // do something when image is loaded completely

})

.error(function(){

    // handle if the image is not loaded

})

.attr('src', 'image source');`

hope this helps,
Regards